# Firebase service-role (admin-level) authentication without SDK causing permission error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rust, oauth-2.0

I am writing a Firebase library for Rust (not relevant, but because of this I am not using an existing SDK). Because there is no SDK for firebase in Rust, I am implementing service-role authentication manually using JWTs. I have been able to authenticate with a JWT generated from a service-role json, however I am getting a "permission denied" error when I go to actually read from any of the collections that aren't set up for public access. When using a service role account with an official SDK library, I do not have such issues. What could be the cause of this? Am I supposed to specify any additional claims when generating the oauth token? It seems to only be giving me user-level access once authenticated instead of the full level of access provided when using a service role key. I can share code snippets if needed, just not too sure what would be relevant to share at this point.

Here is my code for generating the refresh token. Of course I also have code for converting this into an access token etc but if there are any permission issues they'd come from here

```rust
const BASE_URL: &str = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1";

pub async fn get_refresh_token(&mut self) -> Result<(), GetRefreshTokenError> {
        let service_role_file_contents_string = std::fs::read_to_string(&self.service_role_key_path);
        if service_role_file_contents_string.is_err() {
            return Err(GetRefreshTokenError::UnableToReadServiceRoleFile);
        }

        let service_role_file_contents = serde_json::from_str::<HashMap<String, String>>(&service_role_file_contents_string.unwrap());
        if service_role_file_contents.is_err() {
            return Err(GetRefreshTokenError::UnableToReadServiceRoleFile);
        }

        let service_role_file_contents = service_role_file_contents.unwrap();
        let service_role_key = service_role_file_contents.get("private_key");
        if service_role_key.is_none() {
            return Err(GetRefreshTokenError::InvalidServiceRoleFileFormat);
        }
        let service_role_key = service_role_key.unwrap();

        let service_role_email = service_role_file_contents.get("client_email");
        if service_role_email.is_none() {
            return Err(GetRefreshTokenError::InvalidServiceRoleFileFormat);
        }
        let service_role_email = service_role_email.unwrap();

        let current_time = SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH);
        if current_time.is_err() {
            return Err(GetRefreshTokenError::UnableToGetSystemTime);
        }
        let current_time = current_time.unwrap().as_secs();

        let current_time_str = current_time.to_string();

        let expire_time = current_time + 3000;
        let expire_time_str = expire_time.to_string();

        let uuid_str = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();

        let claims = Claims {
            alg: "RS256".to_string(),
            iss: service_role_email.to_string(),
            sub: service_role_email.to_string(),
            aud: "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit".to_string(),
            iat: current_time_str,
            exp: expire_time_str,
            uid: uuid_str,
            admin: "true".to_string()
        };

        let key = encode(&Header::new(Algorithm::RS256), &claims, &EncodingKey::from_rsa_pem(service_role_key.as_bytes()).unwrap());
        if key.is_err() {
            return Err(GetRefreshTokenError::UnableToEncodeKey);
        }
        let key = key.unwrap();

        let url = format!("{}/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key={}", BASE_URL, self.web_api_key);
        let init_client = reqwest::Client::builder().build().unwrap();
        let mut body = HashMap::new();
        body.insert("token", key);
        body.insert("returnSecureToken", "true".to_string());

        let response = init_client
            .post(&url)
            .json(&body)
            .send()
            .await;

        if response.is_err() {
            return Err(GetRefreshTokenError::UnableToMakeWebRequest);
        }
        let response = response.unwrap();

        let res_json = response.json::<serde_json::Value>().await.unwrap();
        println!("{:#?}", res_json);

        self.jwt_expiration_time = res_json.get("expiresIn").unwrap().to_string().replace('"',"").parse::<u64>().unwrap() + current_time;
        self.id_token = Some(res_json.get("idToken").unwrap().to_string().replace('"',""));
        self.refresh_token = Some(res_json.get("refreshToken").unwrap().to_string().replace('"',""));

        Ok(())
}
```

Comment: "*I can share code snippets if needed*" - you should always share code. Otherwise we really don't know what exactly you're doing and what's going wrong. Also, please be clear - it sounds like you're writing a *Firestore* client, not a Firebase client.

Comment: Firestore isn't the only service I am using, but that is the service that allowed me to see there was an issue with the authentication. I'll edit the post to include my oauth code.

Comment: Added the code snippet